# How to resolve file space issue on CDAQ Controller with Labview Test System?

Tags: electrical-engineering, product-testing, labview

**Question:** I am currently encountering Hard Drive Memory space issue to store file on a National Instruments based CDAQ Tester. I am using Labview  2013 SP1 and have to all the software load in the CDAQ Controller.  Some of the basic specifications for the CDAQ are as follows

- Processor: Intel Atom 1.33GHz Dual Core
- Controller OS: Windows Embedded Standard 7
- Hard Drive Memory Size: 16 GB
- Number of Slots: 8

[image]

**Background:** I am trying to control and acquire electrical measurement data from a Keysight 34461A digital multimeter via GBIP using Labview and CDAQ.

[image]

Comment: How much space do you need, and how much do you have? What is the deployment environment -- is it indoors, outdoors, AC mains available, network available, ... ?

Comment: @JoeFriedrichsen, System is an indoor system, AC mains are available, but no network connection. There is no space left, I believe I need about 1-2 GB of space,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Mahendra, I had run into Hard Drive Memory Space issue few months ago on my NI cDAQ. I am using cDAQ-9132 with a 16 GB hard drive, similar to your cDAQ. I was running LabVIEW Professional 2017 SP1 with all softwares installed. The memory space got full when I needed to install some additional drivers.

The cDAQ-9132 is not meant to have a full LabVIEW system running on it. The best practice is to only have LabVIEW run-time engine on the cDAQ and run LabVIEW application which is developed on a full computer with complete LabVIEW system.

To avoid memory space issue, I developed my code on the laptop which has over 200 GB memory space and has a full-fledged LabVIEW system. Once I developed the code I created a standalone application (EXE file) using instruction from the following tutorial: [Distributing Applications with the LabVIEW Application Builder: Stand-Alone Applications](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/3303/en/#toc2) . After that I created an installer for my application which I used to install the LabVIEW runtime engine and the drivers I needed on the cDAQ. You can find step by step instructions to create installer in the following link:[Distributing Applications with the LabVIEW Application Builder:  Installers (Windows)](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/3303/en/#toc5).

Now to cleanup space on the cDAQ, you need to uninstall LabVIEW completely. Go to the control panel in Windows 7 and follow this tutorial:  [Uninstall or Repair National Instruments Software or Drivers in Windows](http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/54335/en/). I have also used Temp File Cleaner which cleaned about 2 GB of space on cDAQ.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

If the built-in storage is fully utilized, there are three other options for saving test data:

1. Save to a network share
2. Save to a USB flash drive
3. Save to an SD card

All of these connections are on the [main front panel](http://www.ni.com/documentation/en/compactdaq-controller/latest/cdaq-9135/pinout/) (items 3, 15, and 10) of the cDAQ controller.

[image: cDAQ Controller Front Panel Diagram]

And the [specifications](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/374668b.pdf) report that the USB controller supports USB 2.0 devices and that the SD controller supports 32 GB cards.